# Bluetooth keeps on disconnecting, even though I am able to connect to a device

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

PLEASE HELP! I am able to connect to a bluetooth device in Ubunbu 20.0.4, but bluetooth keeps on refreshing, and my headphones just keep on connecting and disconnecting.

Comment: In a terminal window, `sudo journalctl --since="-10 minutes", will show you the last 10 minutes of logs, some related to bluetooth.